# Excel cell shall contain required characters

Tags: excel, vba

I would appreciate it if you could help to solve following issue:
When external User fulfil the defined cell in Excel, he/she is allowed to put predefined values within the one cell. Like I want to populate "Country" field and options available for me are: "Moscow" or "Moscow;New-York".

So that acceptable symbols are Latin letters in any case and Semicolon.

If the result is false (for some reasons I used comma after Country name), then the Error message shall be popped up, like "This symbol is not acceptable".

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

Comment: Problem is that `Moscow;New-York` (btw there's no dash in "New York") is one value, not two values. As such you would need the literal value "Moscow;New-York" available to choose from. So you can't achieve this with standard data validation lists. What you *could* do is have a `ListBox` where the user could check/uncheck countries (or is it cities?) and then some code would iterate the list entries and concatenate the selected items into a string that would be come the "Country" (or "City"?) field's value.

Comment: That said, you haven't asked a question about a *specific programming issue* - instead you laid out your requirements and asked for someone to implement them for you... this isn't how this site works. I would recommend *trying something*, getting stuck, then asking about the specific problem you're facing - you'll have a much more pleasant Stack Overflow experience that way.

Comment: Nicely said and *vraiment charmant* :-) - Further readings for the new contributor [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why don't you put a combobox on your sheet, only allowing the user to choose from a predefined list?

Comment: @Dameli You got two answers; if helpful feel free to accept your preferred one by ticking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that OP just wants to prevent the input of certain characters.

These might be detected e.g. by a negative `Like` comparison via

```
    Dim SearchString As String
    SearchString = "Moscow;New-York"        
    If SearchString Like "*[! ;A-Za-z-]*" Then 
        MsgBox "Found not accepted symbol."
        '... do other stuff
    Else
        MsgBox "Correct entry."
    Endif
```

**Hints to pattern search via `"*[! ;A-Za-z-]*"`**

The **`Like` operator** has only some rudimentary ressemblance with pattern searches in *Regular Expressions*, but *can* lead to helpful efficient code, too.

> Especially *"a group of one or more characters ( charlist ) enclosed in brackets ([ ]) can be used to match any single character in string and can include almost any character code, including digits."*

> An **exclamation point (`!`)** at the beginning of such a charlist means that
> a match is made if any character **except** the characters in charlist is found in string.

**The trick**

Therefore it suffices to find just **one** single character **other** than the wanted character sequences (i.e. a blank  , a semicolon `;`, letters within `A-Z` or `a-z` or a hyphen `-`) by a **negative** search pattern prefixed by `!` to find out any *intruder* (the surrounding wild cards `*` allow to identify the intruder at any position).

Note that I positioned the hyphen `-` as *last* element in the pattern search, as within the char list the hyphen is used to identify a range of characters. - *(Contrary to MS Help positioning `-` immediately after `!` doesn't seem to work)*

C.f. [Ms Help Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator)

*The above code splitter doesn't pretend in any way to be a complete solution, but intends to give a starting idea. It's up to the asker to develop further steps in code of his own.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [INSTR function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) to check the cell after editing for specific characters you don't want.

for example:

```
If INSTR(1,cellreference,",")<>”0” then 'a comma was found in the cell
    msgbox "This symbol is not acceptable" 
End if
```